# Does blowing on food cause stomach cancer?

Tags: nutrition, cancer

I recently read a post saying that blowing on food is dangerous because it can cause "Stomach Cancer", and found on google some links like [this one](http://lovelifelust.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/doyouknow-thedangerblowinghotdrink/).

I cannot find attendible references, and moreover I read that not blowing on food is part of Muslims's etiquette so I feel a bit skeptic.

What's the reality?

Comment: following that logic all fizzy drinks are also cancerous, the fizzyness is cause by dissolved C02

Comment: This one is quite ridiculous... The next step is to imply breathing is cancerous because there is a lot of H2O in our mouths / noses and around in the air, which reacts with CO2 we are producing... Also claim doesn't seem to be notable.

Comment: A quick search on this site doesn’t turn up a general question on the whole alkaline blood pH nonsense, of which this is simply an even-more-risible form.

Comment: Looks like the author of that page doesn't like the attention you've given them. Link now says the page is private for me, so I can't enjoy the new conspiracy theory du jour.

Comment: I'm getting the "private site" error on the link, too, so I tried a web search and couldn't find any other examples of this claim, so I'm going to have to question its notability, too.